# change file name shared with bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, share

i send a HTML file by this code :

```
        shareBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/html");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, title[1]);
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_UID, title[1]);
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>"+Html.fromHtml(title[1])+"</title></head><body>"+Html.fromHtml(introText[1])+"</body></html>");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
              }
            });
```

now i wanna know if there is a way to change that HTML file name that sent via bluetooth ???

thank you very much